# FDMemTable Loses FieldDefs information when there is AutoInc Field in Delphi

Tags: delphi, fdmemtable

I am creating a memory table TFDMemTable for a delphi form, and define the fields under FieldDefs. After I am done with the definition of the fields manually, I go to the Fields Editor to add the fields that I just defined.

Everything works perfect until I have an AutoInc type field in my FDMemTable. I am using Delphi 10.3.2 version and I was wondering if I am missing anything or this is a IDE bug.

PS: I have done couple of tests, and I think that if the AutoInc field is not defined as the last field, everything disappears. I am not %100 sure of this case, but pretty much every time I try I loose the fields under FieldDefs.

Here is the steps:

- Place a FDMemTable icon
- Open FieldDefs window
- Create a bunch of fields (string, integer ...)
- define the names, types (and sizes for strings)
- Open FieldsEditor
- Add fields

until here everything works as they should.

- Go back to fieldDefs window
- create and name a new field with autoinc type
- open the fields editor screen and add the last added field.

everything is still good to go as long as there is no more changes in the structure.

Here the weird thing happens if you do the following.

- open FieldDefs window
- create any field ( lets say integer type )
- Go to Fields Editor window to add this last created field.
- and you will see that you don't see this new field to add.
- when you go  back to fieldDefs window to see why it is not showing,
- you will see all the previous and last added fields' definitions gone..

In order for me to go around this problem, I open the form in text form and insert the new field right before the last field which is autoinc,

add field editor entry manually in the text form,

and when everything is right, I toggle to form view.

Comment: How specifically can we reproduce this problem?

Comment: Indeed, please provide detailed steps. Currently I cannot see that over here.

Comment: i tried to add the steps to the question itself..